# How to redirect subpath argument to parameter?

Tags: .htaccess

I want that when person types:

> quizz.pl/emit/myvariable

server will call file emit.php and pass myvariable as the f parameter:

> quizz.pl/emit.php?f=myvariable

I need it to work only when person types "emit".

How to acomplish it using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^/?emit/(.*)$ emit.php?f=$1
</IfModule>
```

The *IfModule* tag will check that the rules are only executed when `mod_rewrite` is installed. The second line activates the `RewriteEngine`. The third line will set the base for you. The next two lines check that if there is a directory or a file which has the same name will be returned instead of some url rewriting.

The `RewriteRule` does the real *magic* it checks if the url beings with emit and puts everything after as a parameter to your `emit.php`.